# A Simple `paste0` Command is Not Working Within a `draw` Command? (ComplexHeatmap, r)

Tags: r, list, draw, heatmap, paste

As part of using ComplexHeatmaps, I need to create a string which will allow me to plot three maps together.

If I have heatmaps `A`, `B` and `C`, I will need to do this,

```
AllMaps <- A + B + C

draw(AllMaps)
```

This will then draw all the heatmaps, `A`, `B` and `C` on one canvas.

However when I try to do this with my list of heatmaps (where `A`, `B` and `C` are stored within `HeatmapList`)...

```
    AllMaps <- paste0("HeatmapList[['", names(HeatmapList[1]),
                       "']] + HeatmapList[['", names(HeatmapList[2]), 
                       "']] + HeatmapList[['", names(HeatmapList[3]), 
                       "']]"
                     )

    draw(AllMaps)
```

It fails and I get the following message:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘draw’ for signature ‘"character"
```

Bizarrely if I then just run `AllMaps` I get:

```
"HeatmapList[['A']] + HeatmapList[['B']] + HeatmapList[['C']]"
```

Showing `paste0` is correctly printing out my list of object names. Then, if I copy and paste that output directly into `draw`, it works! e.g.

```
#This works
draw(HeatmapList[['A']] + HeatmapList[['B']] + HeatmapList[['C']])
```

So what is `paste0` doing with `draw` that it doesn't do when I just run it myself?

Here's an example if you want to run it and see for yourself:

```
#Get the most recent ComplexHeatmaps Package
library(devtools)
install_github("jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap", force = TRUE)
library(ComplexHeatmap)


#Make Example Matrices
Matrices = list()

Matrices[['Mtx1']] <- matrix(  c(2, 4, 5, 7), nrow=2, ncol=2, dimnames = list(c("Row1", "Row2"), c("C.1", "C.2"))) 
Matrices[['Mtx2']] <- matrix(  c(5, 1, 3, 9), nrow=2, ncol=2, dimnames = list(c("Row1", "Row2"), c("C.1", "C.2"))) 
Matrices[['Mtx3']] <- matrix(  c(8, 3, 7, 5), nrow=2, ncol=2, dimnames = list(c("Row1", "Row2"), c("C.1", "C.2"))) 

#Create Heatmaps
HeatmapList = c()

HeatmapList <- lapply(Matrices, function(q) {
  Heatmap(q, name = "a_name") 
})

names(HeatmapList) <- c('A', 'B', 'C')

#Draw a heatmap to check it's all working
draw(HeatmapList[[2]])

#Create Heatmap string so A, B and C can all be plotted together
AllMaps <- (paste0("HeatmapList[['", names(HeatmapList[1]), "']] + ",
                   "HeatmapList[['", names(HeatmapList[2]), "']] + ",
                   "HeatmapList[['", names(HeatmapList[3]), "']]" ))

#Draw using the string we just made --> DOESN"T WORK!
draw(AllMaps)

#Check the string --> LOOKS FINE, JUST AS IT SHOULD BE 
paste0(AllMaps)

# Copy and paste string manually into draw command --> THIS WORKS
draw(HeatmapList[['A']] + HeatmapList[['B']] + HeatmapList[['C']])

#SO WHY DOES THIS FAIL???
draw(AllMaps)
```

Comment: @RonakShah, So rather than is just dumping `A, B, C` is it actually using `"A, B, C"` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AllMaps` is just a plain string and when you pass it in the `draw` function instead of taking it as `HeatmapList` object it evaluates it as a character and hence it gives the error message. One option is to use `eval(parse(text` to evaluate the string as `HeatmapList` object

```
draw(eval(parse(text = AllMaps)))
```

Although this works but using `eval(parse` is usually not recommended.

If you check the `class` of `AllMaps` it is character

```
class(AllMaps)
#[1] "character"
```

and if you check

```
class(HeatmapList[['A']] + HeatmapList[['B']] + HeatmapList[['C']])

#[1] "HeatmapList"
#attr(,"package")
#[1] "ComplexHeatmap"
```

so we need to bring those individual objects in `HeatmapList` class.

We can use a simple `for` loop

```
HeatmapList = c()

for (i in seq_len(length(Matrices))) {
  HeatmapList = HeatmapList + Heatmap(Matrices[[i]], name = "a_name") 
}
```

and now use `draw` method on `HeatmapList` which would give us the expected output

```
draw(HeatmapList)
```

[image]